# How to display articles' image in Joomla search results

Tags: image, search, joomla, article

Is there a way to modify the code of the Joomla's search component so it can display even the article's image?

I have made a simple code that can search the image or youtube video in the article's text and return the media including the required tags as a string, but where do I put it?

```
// SEARCH IMAGE OR VIDEO
$hasImage = 0;
$hasVideo = 0;
$articleMedia = '';
$articleText = $text;

// has image?
preg_match_all('/<\s?img[^>]+\>/i', $articleText, $matches);
    if(isset($matches['0']['0']))
        {
        $articleMedia = $matches['0']['0'] ;
        $hasImage = 1;
        }

// no image? maybe video
if ($hasImage == 0) {
    preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))/i', $articleText, $matches);
    if(isset($matches['0']['0']))
        {
        $articleMediaID = $matches['2']['0'] ;
        $articleMedia = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" . $articleMediaID;
        $hasVideo = 1;
        } else {
            preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))/i', $articleText, $matches1);
            if( isset($matches1['0']['0']) ){
                $articleMediaID = $matches1['2']['0'] ;
                $articleMedia = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" . $articleMediaID;
                $hasVideo = 1;
                }
        }


    if ( $hasVideo == 1){
            $articleMedia = '<iframe class="youtube" width="100%"  src="' . $articleMedia . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
            }
}

// END SEARCH IMAGE OR VIDEO
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `search` [plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin), it's very simple to to create one, especially as you've worked out your core code already.

Depending on the type of Joomla search you're using you should read either:

1. [Creating a Search Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin)
2. [Creating a Smart Search Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in)